# Missing-data in a rather small group of participants

Tags: t-test, missing-data

Hi all and thank you for your valuable help all through my research work :)

I am not by any means expert in statistics, I am a psychiatrist doing my phD in the area om medical education and I have come to this point of my work where I struggle with analysing my results. Here comes my question:

I have a group of 32 students that filled in a knowledge test consisting of 11 multiple choice questions, before and after an educational moment as well as some months later. The last test was performed through a special platform in the internet. The first two were on site. I intent to do some graphs and t-tests to look at and compare the results before and after.

My "problem" is that i have some drop outs during the last follow-up. Six of them did not fill in the last follow-up knowledge test. How would you handle a situation like this? Exclude those 6 persons from the analysis over-all? It feels like a waste, since I have a rather small sample to begin with...

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 3 cents:

1) You should not drop them from the entire analysis, as they will still likely contribute valuable information for parts of it (those not involving the final follow-up).

2) Given your sample size, and the fact that missingness is due to their dropping out (and thus I assume that are missing all information collected at follow-up), it is highly unlikely that you can employ multiple imputation to address the missing data. In other words, you are probably stuck with it.

3) However, your sample size is likely to limit your ability to confidently make statistical inferences anyway. Your instinct to analyze the data visually is a good one, and I don't think that any statistical testing or modelling will add much more value to that.